# Cannot telnet to port after installing Active Directory and DNS Server

Tags: dns, active-directory, telnet

I have a machine running Windows Server 2008 R2 in my network on which we have installed Software AG products. To access these products, we open their console webpage in our web browsers, like this: `http://172.19.50.121:8585` and `http://172.19.50.121:5555`. These are two separate applications, running on these ports.

Before installing Active Directory and DNS Server on this machine, I was able to open these webpages from other machines within the network. But now I installed Active Directory and DNS Server on this machine, and I can no longer open these sites from outside the machine.

I can however, open them from inside the machine, by opening the sites: `http://localhost:8585` and `http://localhost:5555`.

I think this has something to do with the DNS Server that got installed. I tried disabling the DNS Server service but that didn't resolve the issue.

Can someone help me out here ?

Comment: Windows Firewall? I'm wondering though why you promoted a server running an application to a domain controller?

Comment: Yep I just saw it myself too .. It was a Domain Firewall problem which was rejecting Inbound connections which didn't match a rule .. Anyways thanks ! :) ... And I installed an Active Directory as our application under development needed to work with LDAP, so we installed it to test it out ..

Comment: OK, so it's not a production server. I'm going to make my comment an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check Windows Firewall, it sounds like there is a rule that has blocked these ports.